# Android facebook sdk 4.1.0 set image to login button

Tags: android, facebook-login

I want to set only custom image to facebook login button. But it display logo of facebook when i set image to login button.

My xml code is as follows,

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFacebookLogin"
            style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            fb:com_facebook_login_text=""
            fb:com_facebook_logout_text=""
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

style,

```
<style name="FacebookLoginButton">
    <item name="android:layout_height">42dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10sp</item>
</style>
```

But no setting properly. I want to set this image only,
[image]

Please help me to set this image only. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set image to Facebook Login via XML.

**You need to set it programatically.**

```
        btnFacebookLogin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fb);
        btnFacebookLogin.setText("");
        btnFacebookLogin.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
```

**in XML:**

```
  <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/btnFacebookLogin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                       
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    fb:com_facebook_login_text=""
                    fb:com_facebook_logout_text="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to style your button as per you want

```
<style name="FacebookLoginButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/smallTxtSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/facebook_signin_btn</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

in your xml

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFacebookLogin"
            style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            fb:com_facebook_login_text=""
            fb:com_facebook_logout_text=""
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

or else give programatically

```
final LoginButton button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.facebook);
```

Comment: did you set background in style

Answer (score 0):

To remove the little **f** icon from the original login button, add this to your java **LoginButton** instannce :

```
mButtonLogin.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
```

Adjust the **width** and the **height** via **paddingLeft**, **paddingRight**, **paddingBottom** and **paddingTop**.

```
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="96dp"
        android:paddingRight="96dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        facebook:com_facebook_login_text=""
        facebook:com_facebook_logout_text="" />
```